# How to resolve could not satisfy version constraints in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am using a large monolitic Chef repository. From time to time I run into dependency problems with messages similar to

> Could not satisfy version constraints for:

This is one of things about Chef that I don't understand. It seems that the only way to resolve these issues is to manually create a dependency tree in order to check where this error originates from.

Is there not a more advanced way in Chef to troubleshoot these issues. Is there a tool / utility that can do this?

The best / only way I found to do this is trial and error fiddle with dependencies and provision after each change untill the offending depedency is found. Which could very well take days.

Answer (score 0):

The `knife-solve` gem gives you an interactive tool for playing with the solver, and you can use Policyfiles to totally bypass the server side solver. Beyond that, there isn't a ton. Berks has a detailed solver debug output but I can be hard to get it in exactly the same scenario as your Chef Server.